# Adding panel-heading:hover class in bootstrap less does not change the hover color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, hover, less

I have added the following lines to `bootstrap/less/panels.less`

```
//hover color for panel heading
.panel-heading:hover {
  background-color: #dfdfdf;
}
```

But it wouldn't load to the css in the browser. yet I can manually add it in the css editor (in chrome dev tools) and it works.

Any solutions  ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it works in chrome dev tools and in css file not, that means it is overwritten from other rule. You can overwrite the rule by increasing the specificity (e.g. concatenate another class name or some other selector), or, to be sure, use "!important":

```
.panel-heading:hover {
  background-color: #dfdfdf !important;
}
```